# Is this correct to say "this car is made out of leaves" or "this car is made of leaves" or "this car is made from leaves"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

[image]

Which one is correct to express the above picture?

"**this car is made out of leaves**"

"**this car is made of leaves**"

"**this car is made from leaves**"?

Comment: All are fine and express the idea.  *made of leaves* or *made from leaves* would be the proper way to express it.  *Made out of leaves* would be a conversational way to express it.  Those leaves look a lot like grass.

Comment: yeah, the grammar is fine -- but we don't normally use the word "leaves".for a collection of grass.

Comment: @JasonBassford, I know that rule, but how do we apply it for specific items? You can't say "I know the theory or rule of Administration, so I can manage any company". But it is important that how we apply it

Comment: @JasonBassford, everyone knows "on" and "in" mean, but many people don't know if they say "the key is on the keychain" or "the key is in the keychain". That is why English is so hard because you can only gain it through experience, not through the English rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three are grammatically correct, with slightly different meaning. However, "leaves" isn't typically used to describe grass, so I will change it to say grass instead.

**This car is made of grass** tells us what the material in the car is.

**This car is made out of grass** means the same thing. It is considered better style to not include the word "out" because it isn't necessary.

**This car is made from grass** emphasizes *how* the car was made. It says the car's material was grass before it was used to make the car. It's correct, and it sounds natural even if the material does not change.

The difference can be demonstrated by an example: "Bread is made *from* wheat" is correct, because wheat is used to make flour, which is used to make bread. "Bread is made *of* wheat" is not correct, because the wheat was changed into something else when it was made into bread. (This is a minor difference, and people will understand you if you use the wrong one.)

Comment: _Bread is made of wheat_ is also wrong because it usually means "and nothing else", which is false for bread. _Made from_ doesn't have that implication.